# Is there a way to display values different based on date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to grab data vertically and display it horizontally with a column in between each value.

Here is example data:[image]

Here is what I'm trying to get it to do: [image]

I've tried exhausting everything I currently know to figure this out but I can't seem to get it and I believe it's an easy problem to fix. I'm just not having much luck with my keywords in google.

ps: just noticed I had some columns hidden still. In this case lets pretend the columns in examples are A/B/C/D/E.

Comment: In the second example the row with 12/19/2018 I would have guessed the run2 would have a 35 in it.  Explain why not and post your [mcve]. Please explain what you're doing to get from example 1 to example 2.

Answer (score 0):

## Summarizing identical dates on multiple rows into separate columns on the same row

I don't completely understand how you went from example 1 to example 2 but it is clear that you want to summarize multiple rows with the same date into multiple columns on one row and that's what this function is an example of.

I'm guessing that once you provide a better explanation of what your trying to accomplish and how it's supposed to work then you may get some answers that are a lot easier to figure out.

Anyway I offer this solution as a possibility that you can start with if you like.  I'm using a key/value object to keep track of the number of identical dates and if the method dObj.hasOwnProperty() returns false then it also helps to identify new dates.

The Code:

```
function condenseDates(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');//you need to change this for the appropriate sheet name
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();//get all data values including headers
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dObj={};//data object which is used to identify new new dates and keep track of the run columns for identical dates.
  var d=0;//delete counter
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(dObj.hasOwnProperty(vA[i][0])) {//if it does not have this property then it is a new date
      dObj[vA[i][0]]=Number(dObj[vA[i][0]])+1;//if it does have this property then increment the DObj value which keeps track of the run column it will go into
      var rg=sh.getRange(1,2 + Number(dObj[vA[i][0]]));//this is the header column cell for this dObj column
      if(rg.isBlank()){//if it is blank then write a new one
        rg.setValue('Run' + dObj[vA[i][0]]);
      }
      sh.getRange(Number(dObj.currentRow),2 + Number(dObj[vA[i][0]])).setValue(vA[i][1]);//put value for this line in the appropriate column in the currentRow   
      sh.deleteRow(i-d+1);//delete this line
      d++;//increment the delete counter
    }else{//it is a new date
      dObj[vA[i][0]]=1;
      dObj['currentRow']=i-d+1;//Current Data Row
      var rg=sh.getRange(1,3);
      if(rg.isBlank()){//if header has no label in the first run column then write it
        rg.setValue('Run' + 1);
      }
      sh.getRange(Number(dObj.currentRow),2 + Number(dObj[vA[i][0]])).setValue(vA[i][1]);//write data in the appropriate column in this case it is always column3 
    }
  }
  sh.deleteColumn(2);
}
```

The Example Spreadsheet before running the script:

[image]

The Example Spreadsheet after running the script:

The value in column 2 for each consecutive identical date is placed in the next column on the first row in which that date appears.  At the end column2 is deleted.

[image]

- [Javascript Object Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)
- [SpreadsheetApp Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

I played around with this and this version doesn't required additional identical dates to be consecutive. It create a unique currentRow for each date and that current row is used for all remaining identical dates even if they occur after other remaining dates.  ie the dates don't have to be sorted.

```
function condenseDates(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('36');//you need to change this for the appropriate sheet name
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();//get all data values including headers
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dObj={};//data object which is used to identify new new dates and keep track of the run columns for identical dates.
  var d=0;//delete counter
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(dObj.hasOwnProperty(vA[i][0])) {//if it does not have this property then it is a new date
      dObj[vA[i][0]]=Number(dObj[vA[i][0]])+1;//if it does have this property then increment the DObj value which keeps track of the run column it will go into
      var rg=sh.getRange(1,2 + Number(dObj[vA[i][0]]));//this is the header column cell for this dObj column
      if(rg.isBlank()){//if it is blank then write a new one
        rg.setValue('Run' + dObj[vA[i][0]]);
      }
      sh.getRange(Number(dObj[vA[i][0].toString()+'currentRow']),2 + Number(dObj[vA[i][0]])).setValue(vA[i][1]);//put value for this line in the appropriate column in the currentRow   
      sh.deleteRow(i-d+1);//delete this line
      d++;//increment the delete counter
    }else{//it is a new date
      dObj[vA[i][0]]=1;
      dObj[vA[i][0].toString()+'currentRow']=i-d+1;//A unique Current Data Row for each date when additional identical dates will expand into additional columns.
      var rg=sh.getRange(1,3);
      if(rg.isBlank()){//if header has no label in the first run column then write it
        rg.setValue('Run' + 1);
      }
      sh.getRange(Number(dObj[vA[i][0].toString()+'currentRow']),2 + Number(dObj[vA[i][0]])).setValue(vA[i][1]);//write data in the appropriate column in this case it is always column3 
    }
  }
  sh.deleteColumn(2);
}
```